# How to read a file content in ash into an argument?

Tags: shell, unix, ash

I'm trying to read a file which holds a single number in ash shell. The bash way of doing so

```
ARG=`cat /tmp/tempfile`
```

doesn't work and I get that ARG doesn't hold anything after this line of code.

Comment: This should work just fine. Are you sure the file isn't empty?

Comment: I'm sure, when I print the value: echo "stored value= $ARG"  there is nothing after the "=". Also when I run this code on my computer with bash it works fine.

Comment: could you give us the surrounding lines of code so we can check if it comes from another reason (ex: read in a subshell?). and be sure that there is no space around the = in "var=value".  to try to pinpoint the pb : write  `cat /tmp/tempfile ; read THEARG</tmp/tempfile ; echo "THEARG=$THEARG"` : the idea is there to be sure the file is readable, and only 1 line, and changing the ARG into THEARG to be sure it was not a reserved word in ash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to surround it with quotes to have it not stopped at the first newline:

```
ARG="`cat /tmp/tempfile`"
```

or

```
ARG="$(cat /tmp/tempfile)"
```

or

```
read ARG  </tmp/tempfile #only 1st line will be read
```

Comment: The sample with UUOC will probably not work, since (in most shells) the read will run in a subshell.  But the redirection to read will work in any posix compliant shell.

Comment: @William oops, very very correct, and I can't believe I fell for that one when I usually spot it in other's scripts ^^ I edit my answer. Thanks!